# Question on lub/glb property: unclear definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Rudin defines an ordered set $S$ to have the *least upper bound* property $$\exists \alpha = sup E \in S$$ if the following is true:

> 1. $E \subset S$
> 2. E is non-empty
> 3. E is bounded above

So the assumption I am trying to make is that $sup E \in E$ is possible for some sets $E$ because $$\forall e \in E, \hspace{5 pt}  \exists \alpha \in E : e \leq \alpha$$

Of course this definition wouldn't fit in finding the square root of 2 for the rationals, so that is why I specified some sets "$E$".

Am I correct?

Comment: I don't understand what $\exists \alpha = sup E \in S$ is supposed to mean. Inside the grey box, what is $E$? It's not quantified.

Comment: I've noticed in a number of your questions and answers, your confusion seems to stem for a serious lack of precision in the definitions. For example, in this question, it's extremely unclear since you haven't stated what $E$ is until after using it, and $E$ is never quantified. I think that a general lack of precision and care about the meaning of words is leading to a number of problems for you.

Comment: If T. Bongers is right and you wish to remedy this, I suggest going through [How to Prove It: A Structured Approach](http://www.amazon.com/How-Prove-It-Structured-Approach/dp/0521446635), by [D.J. Velleman](http://www.cs.amherst.edu/~djv/).

Comment: I doubt Rudin wrote it like that.

Comment: I think the person meant, "there exists a supremum, call it $\alpha$, if the following holds". The supremum is in $S$, but in some cases might or might not be in $E$. Check that the supremum is a limit point, so for instance if $E$ is closed, it would contain all of its limit points and hence $\alpha$. Easy examples is the $E=(0,1)$ here $\alpha=1$ and its not in $E$, and also $E=[0,1]$, here $\alpha=1$ too, but in this case $\alpha\in E$.

Comment: I believe it would be useful to you to avoid condensed notations for a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments, your paraphrase of the definition of the least upper bound property is incorrect to the point of not actually making sense as written. Here is a correct version:

> Let $S$ be an ordered set. Then $S$ has the *least upper bound property* if the following is true: whenever $E$ is a non-empty subset of $S$ that is bounded above, $E$ has a least upper bound, or supremum, in $S$. This supremum is denoted by $\sup E$ and has the following property: if $\alpha=\sup E$, $s\in S$, and $s$ is an upper bound for $E$ (i.e., $e\le s$ for all $e\in E$), then $\alpha\le s$.

It is true that any ordered set $S$ has non-empty subsets $E$ such that $\sup E\in E$: every non-empty finite subset of $S$ has this property. For that matter, if $e$ is any fixed member of $S$, the set $E=\{s\in S:s\le e\}$ has the property: $\sup E=e\in E$.

However, your expression $\forall e\in E\;\exists\alpha\in E(e\le\alpha)$ has nothing to do with this: it is a statement that is true of **every** ordered set $E$. To see this, merely observe that if $e\in E$, we can take $\alpha=e$, and it will certainly be true that $e\le\alpha$. (If $E=\varnothing$, the statement is true vacuously.) I suspect that you actually had in mind the statement $\exists\alpha\in E\,\forall e\in E(e\le\alpha)$; this is a completely different statement that **does** say that $E$ has a maximum element $\alpha$. The order of the quantifiers makes a huge difference.

Your statement says, in English, that

> for each element $e$ of $E$ we can find an element $\alpha$ of $E$ that is at least as big as $e$.

Of course we can: $e$ is an element of $E$ that is at least as big as $e$.

The statement that I think you intended says, in English, that

> there is an element $\alpha$ of $E$ that is at least as big as **every** element of $E$.

That’s completely different: that says that $\alpha$ is the biggest element of $E$.

I agree with André Nicolas that it would be a good idea for you to write things out using more words and less compressed notation: this might help you to pay attention to what you’re actually saying and to see when it doesn’t quite make sense.

In $\Bbb R$ there are many non-empty sets that are bounded above but do not contain their suprema: every non-empty open interval $(a,b)$ is such a set, since $\sup(a,b)=b\notin(a,b)$. I suspect that in your final comment you were thinking of the ordered set $\Bbb Q$ and its subset

$$E=\{q\in\Bbb Q:q<0\text{ or }q^2<2\}\;,$$

which is the lefthand side of a Dedekind cut in $\Bbb Q$. This is an example showing that $\Bbb Q$ does **not** have the least upper bound property: $E$ is bounded above (e.g., by $2$) and is certainly non-empty, but if $\alpha\in\Bbb Q$ is an upper bound for $E$, there is a $\beta\in\Bbb Q$ such that $\beta<\alpha$ and $\beta$ is also an upper bound for $E$. The expression $\sup E$ is undefined in $\Bbb Q$. Of course in $\Bbb R$ the set $E$ **does** have a least upper bound, namely, $\sqrt2$.

Comment: I get it now Brian!!!!!!

Comment: @Don: Excellent!